# Get all JSON return data using another php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

In console log I see following data is return using json_encode(); Check this attached image.

[image]

When I click on Send button it's calling **submit.php** page showing data using

```
<?php
  print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

it's showing me

```
Array ( [data] => Shibbir, )
```

**BUT** I want to get the `cdid`and `label` key value as you can see my attached image that in console log it's showing cdid and label value.

**html code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple, remote</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <style>
  .ui-autocomplete-loading {
    background: white url("loading-image.gif") right center no-repeat;
  }

  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }

    $( "#birds" )
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
      .autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
          $.getJSON( "search.php", {
            term: extractLast( request.term )
          }, response );
        },
        search: function() {
          // custom minLength
          var term = extractLast( this.value );
          if ( term.length < 2 ) {
            return false;
          }
        },
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var terms = split( this.value );
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
          terms.push( "" );
          this.value = terms.join( ", " );
          return false;
        }
      });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="submit.php" name="form">   
<div class="ui-widget">
  <input type="text" id="birds" name="data" size="50">
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</div>
</form>   
</body>
</html>
```

**search.php page**

```
<?php
require_once("../frontend/config.php");
$term = $_GET['term'];
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT cdid, family_name, given_name FROM contact_details WHERE family_name LIKE '%$term%' ");
 $return_arr = array();
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['cdid'] = $row['cdid'];
    $row_array['label'] = $row['family_name'];


    array_push($return_arr, $row_array);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);    
?>
```

Comment: I don't get it, you're submitting a form the regular way as x-www-form-urlencoded, and you've somehow managaged to print some JSON in the browser, but it's not really clear what you're doing, the image of the console log doesn't match the elements in the form at all ?

Comment: @adeneo attached image have `cdid` and `label` which is comes from 'search.php' page. plz check update question.

Comment: So you're not submitting the form the regular way, now you suddenly have jQuery, autocomplete, JSON results and a lot more stuff going on. Try tagging the question correctly and adding all the relevant code

Comment: Yes, I'm not submitting the form in regular way. When I type on input fields it's call search.php page and return result on input box using json. After when I press the send button I want to show the `cdid` and `label` value.